# Get all matching units from string

Tags: python, pint

I am using pint 0.23 and I faced the following problem.

I have a unit in short format (`dat`). It can refer to `deci-technical_atmosphere` or `deca-metric_ton`. Here is what I do at the moment

```
>> import pint
>> ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
>> d = "[denisty]"
>> ureg.Unit("dat")
<Unit('decitechnical_atmosphere')>
```

How can I force it to give me the `deca-metric_ton` as it should be a `[density]`?

Comment: To my knowledge you can't have an alias refer to 2 units simultaneously. Whichever one you define last is used.

Comment: The code example given doesn't define any aliases, "dat" seems built-in and references `decitechnical_atmosphere`. I am not sure what the purpose of the line `d = "[density]"` is, it's typo'd and then never used, anyway.

Comment: The line `d = "[density]"` doesn't do anything so far. I just placed it there to define the variable name that could be used.
You are correct I rely on the default unit definition that comes with pint